# restkit json example

Tags: ios, json, restkit

I'm just starting off with RestKit for iOS.
after figuring out some concepts and head-points for the RestKit, I've moved to start some practical training on RestKit. But what I've found is all the examples and the tutorials about RestKit are outdated and there is no example on the new version .

What i want is a small and simple example on how Restkit deal with JSON (Request and Response) and how to use ObjectMapping 2.0 (live example)

I've been reading through [this web page](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/wiki) since 3 days and i came over all of it's stuff and acquire a good amount of knowledge about it, but still with no benefit for what I want.

Thx in advance

Answer (score 4):

You best place to start is download restKit from github and working through the examples that are built in.

https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/tree/master/Examples

That is a good place to start and generally kept up to date.

Comment: those are complex examples i need to learn the basic concept first. anyway thanks

Comment: I'm looking for an example just like this http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/restkit_ios-sdk/ but on the updated version

Answer (score 3):

Blake has written a great writeup at https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/blob/master/Docs/Object%20Mapping.md I don't know if was update to handle the very recent release but it certainly worked on the previous one.

Comment: I've been here but i need a full example or a tutorial i can't match between the old version and the new one anyway thanks.

Comment: I'm looking for an example just like this http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/restkit_ios-sdk/ but on the updated version

Comment: The tutorials that Paul linked to are the most up to date I know of, and the examples in the Restkit code base (in my link https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/tree/master/Examples) are updated (as far as I know) as RestKit is updated. I would start by bending them to your needs to get a better understanding of what they do. Good luck!